# Python Code runs in Mac terminal but not from Neovim

Tags: python, python-3.x, vim, neovim

I recently learned the basics of Vim (NeoVim) and started going through the tutorial for Python 3 on the Python website.  I wrote this simple script, `ask.py`:

```
def ask_ok(prompt, retries=4, reminder='Please try again!'):    
    while True:    
        ok = input(prompt)    
        if ok in ('y', 'ye', 'yes'):    
            return True    
        if ok in ('n', 'no', 'nop', 'nope'):    
            return False    
        retries = retries - 1    
        if retries < 0:    
            raise ValueError('invalid user response')    
        print(reminder)    
            
ask_ok("Here is a question", 3, "Give a better answer!")
```

To test the function defined in 4.7.1 here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

When I quit Neovim and run either `python3 ask.py` or `python ask.py` the script runs.  However when I enter Neovim and run `:!python3 ask.py` or `:!python ask.py` I get this error:

```
!python ask.py 
Here is a questionTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "ask.py", line 13, in <module>
    ask_ok("Here is a question", 3, "Give a better answer!")
  File "ask.py", line 3, in ask_ok
    ok = input(prompt)
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

shell returned 1
```

Why is the error returned the script when run from Neovim, but not when I run it directly in the terminal?

Comment: When you run a command with `!`, standard input is not connected to the terminal.

Comment: OK  thanks! Because I'm new at this, standard input just means "python listening form my keystrokes followed by a the return key" right?

Comment: A more common development pattern w/ vim and python is to use tmux to split your terminal into say vim on the left pane and some REPL like ipython on the right for testing.  Backgrounding vim w/ ctrl z, running your script then fg to return to vim also works.

Comment: thanks! the ctrl z/ fg trick seems easier for now.  will try the second one if I ever feel ready for tmux and learn what ipython is and wha a REPL is